# Android Studio does not recognise my imported libraries (No Adminstrator, using a proxy at work)

Tags: java, android, proxy, dependencies, libraries

I am trying to add the library 
"com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0" and "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0"  in Android Studio and have done everything the tutorials asked me to do, yet it doesnt work.

These are my dependencies after i added them:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-31027299/Dependencies.jpg.html

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.programmierenlernenhq.aktiehq.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

This is my SDK Manager:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-31027308/SDKManager.png.html

I did all of this, yet I get the Error "Unused import statement" at the line "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;" and "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;".

I am doing this at work without administrative rights and behind a proxy. I am having the feeling that the problem might be there. Hopefully you know more about this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: try open your SDK manager and check weather this support repo is dowloaded or not. If not then there might me proxy issue.

Comment: @DrupDesai According to my SDK Manager (as shown in the picture i linked) the Android Support Repository is already installed. Am I maybe misinterpreting something in the manager? I am new to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

There is no `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0` yet.
Please use: `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0`
If You are unsure of the library version, you can always [check it here](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.android.support%3Asupport-v4%3A23.4.0)

Comment: all this are available but in alpha and beta stages.

Comment: With this i get the error "This support library should not use a different version (23) than the compiledSDKversion(24)"

Comment: So You might consider changing `compileSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file to 23.
Or use `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1` and `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1`

Comment: @R.Zagórski I tried both and nothing works. Is there maybe another step after this to get rid of errors? I am new to Android Studio.